# Dropdown <option> isn't passing to Firestore Database Angular

Tags: html, angular, database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a form and all data is passing to my Firestore Database as expected with the exception of my dropdown selection  and I'm not sure why this is. Any ideas?

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name Of  Company:</label>
        <select type="text" formControlName="companyName" id="companyName">
            <option > Company Name </option>
            <option value="Company Name 1">Company Name 1</option>
            <option value="Company Name 2">Company Name 2</option>
            <option value="Company Name 3">Company Name 3</option>
            <option value="Company Name 4">Company Name 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Found the Issue, Kind of.**

So it turns out that the reason this form is not sending the dropdown information to the database is due to some inline css, more specifically a component set to **`display: none;**`. When I disable this in the Elements -> styles within the console it sends the data as expected.

However, I still haven't found where this element is located in the code or a way to disable it permanently, but it's a start.

**Issue Resolved**

The display:none issue I mentioned earlier had to do with bootstrap 4 properties when utilizing the nice-select plugin. I simply uninstalled the nice-select plugin and used the native select option with a little css and everything worked perfectly. I tried to find a workaround, but after several hours I decided it was faster to move forward without the plugin.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new here and am getting the hang of stack overflow. I've been working on this for about six hours and didn't keep track of everything over time as I assumed it was a simple problem and I'd eventually figure it out. I'll recreate some of the things I've tried and update it.

Answer (score 1):

This part is working if this is not working for you then you need to look at migration table id/name in model or function.

```
<form action="">

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
          <label>Name Of  Company:</label>
            <select formControlName="companyName" id="companyName">
              <option > Company Name </option>
              <option value="Company Name 1">Company Name 1</option>
              <option value="Company Name 2">Company Name 2</option>
              <option value="Company Name 3">Company Name 3</option>
              <option value="Company Name 4">Company Name 4</option>
          </select>
  </div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer sent me looking at other avenues. I updated the post with what I've found up to this point.